# Java Eclipse Combo Box Resizing Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, combobox

I am writing some Java Eclipse code to plug into our main commercial software package. I am having a problem with combo box that I was hoping for some ideas to help me resolve the issue.

The environment uses SWT and Teamcenter has a control called a LOVComboBox that inherits from a combo box that I am using to display information.

The issue I am having is that I defined the width of my LOVComboBox with the following code:

```
 LOVComboBox combDept1 = new LOVComboBox(scrolledForm.getBody(), SWT.NONE | SWT.BORDER);
 combDept1.setBounds(10, 100, 250, 23);
```

When I click on the down arrow to show the combo box information, the actual width of the data displayed exceeds the width that I have defined for this control, in this case 250.

What happens is that the entire control is resized automatically and it is causing problems with the other controls I have placed around this control.

Do you know of anyway I can stop the control from automatically resizing?

Comment: can you share an image of what you are seeing?

Comment: Using `setBounds` is going to cause endless problems like this. Learn to use [Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm) which will adjust the layout to take in to account the size each control requires.

Comment: I'd be happy to, I'm not sure how I can embed a screenshot of the issue, any suggestions?

Comment: @greg-449, I removed the setbounds and the problem still persists, I appreciate the suggestion however i don't believe this issue is related to me not using a Layout to display data.